# git rebase requires signature for each commit

Tags: git

I have set up git to sign my commits. However, when doing a rebase it wants to sign each and every commit from the rebase point. This includes commits that I didn't write.

Since the token I use takes about 4 seconds for each signature, and asks for my pincode as well, you can imagine this wildly slows down doing a rebase. Is there a way to convince git *not* to do this, while maintaining the behaviour where it signs *my* commits by default?

Comment: You've just discovered one of the main reasons hardly anyone uses the commit-signing feature. If you sign only annotated tags, this problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

A rebase in Git consists of two main logical steps:

1. rewinding your branch and applying the new commits from the source branch, and
2. reapplying all your commits on top of the new base

Note carefully that in the second step Git is actually making *new* commits using your original commits.  The reason they are actually new commits is that in general the content might change, e.g. from resolving merge conflicts.

As you are making new commits, if you require signing, that requirement would apply to all reapplied commits during a rebase as well.  So, your options here are either to put up with the current behavior, or maybe try to turn off signing.

Comment: I get that it's making new commits - but it's not making them in _my_ name, so I don't want my signature attached to it in any case.

Comment: Well what can you do?  _You_ are the one who is reapplying those commits.  Are you asking if Git can use someone else's signature?  Even if it could, would that other person really want that to happen?

Comment: @MartijnOtto *it's not making them in my name* It is. Every commit has an author and a committer. On rebase `git` preserves the author but changes the committer to be *you*.